# Selection Of coupling and determining size of motor to rotate heavy disc

Tags: design, stepper-motor

Following image is something I want to design. The uniform stainless steel round plate of diameter 1000mm and thickness 10mm is rotated by a stepper motor. But after every turn, a pressure of 3000 kg/cm^2 is applied at he edge of the plate by a hydraulic piston. Will my disc deflect? Does it need a support at bottom where pressure is applied? How should I couple my motor to the disc so that the coupling can withstand the load? Can my motor withstand such pressure? 
Please help me with the design.After ever turn the plate stops and pressure is applied. Which stepper can withstand such load?[image: System Design]

Comment: your question has nothing to do with robotics per se ... it also shows that you may have a misunderstanding of how materials behave when exposed to several tonnes of pressure

Comment: Your question makes sense if you apply a *force* to the disk.  You cite a *pressure*, but do not give an area.  So, your question makes no sense.  Please edit.

Comment: This would make a lot more sense on engineering.stackexchange -- it has nothing to do with robotics per se., and a lot to do with mechanical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions here, and not really enough information to answer them...

- Will my disc deflect? Yes. How *far* it will deflect and whether or not that is a problem depends on the force applied (you have not said - the pressure in the piston is not enough information on its own).
- Does it need a support at bottom where pressure is applied? Maybe? This depends on how much deflection is acceptable, see above.
- How should I couple my motor to the disc so that the coupling can withstand the load? I would recommend *decoupling* the motor from the disc. You don't want to use the motor shaft to support it. Something like a soft jaw coupling will allow the motor to keep driving even as the disk deflects. You then need to support the disk on a separate shaft, which can be much beefier and less sensitive than the motor.
- Can my motor withstand such pressure? As mentioned above, it's not recommended to take any force on a motor shaft.
- Which stepper can withstand such load? Once you've successfully decoupled the load, you can pick any stepper with suitable performance re: spinning your disc.